# Has there been much research on the Iwasawa theory of bi-quadratic fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, iwasawa-theory

The simplest non-trivial example of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions happen over imaginary quadratic fields and I've seen a good amount of research done here (from my understanding still a lot to learn).  I would think that the next step up in complexity would be looking at the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions of bi-quadratic fields, say $k = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m}, \sqrt{n})$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are square free.  I've been searching around but can't seem to find any work done in this area.  In particular, I'm interested in Iwasawa's $\lambda$-invariant for the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension over $k$.  Does anyone know of any papers or research that have to do with this?  Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**  After a bit of thought I realized that this may not be so interesting.  I think that we can determine $\lambda^-$ (the minus part of Iwasawa's lambda invariant for the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension) from the $\lambda$-invariants of the two imaginary subfields of $k$.  That is, $\lambda^- = \lambda_{\chi_1} + \lambda_{\chi_2}$, where $\chi_1, \chi_2$ are the odd characters belonging the imaginary quadratic subfields.  We have $\lambda = \lambda^- + \lambda^+$, but $\lambda^+$ is expected to be 0 by Vandiver's conjecture.